# Keeping track of time

Tags: python, time

I need my functions to get updated with new time values each second, is there a better way of keeping track than setting t1 the checking if t2 - t1 = 1 ?

Edit hopefully for better clarity:
The orbit code:

```
def orbit(center, radius, speed, t):
    theta = math.fmod(t * speed, math.pi * 2)
    c = math.cos(theta)
    s = math.sin(theta)
    x = int(round(center[0] + radius * c))
    y = int(round(center[1] + radius * s))
    coords=[x, y]
    return coords
```

What i need is to change t in that while calling it from a draw function, what i need is to limit fps and calculate t for every frame. I only see a get_fps function in pygame which returns what the fps is not set it or am i wrong?

Comment: You seem to already have a solution, but you haven't specified what you think might be wrong with it.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: It seems like he's having trouble implementing the answer to his previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058591/making-smooth-orbits-in-pygame . It's about circular orbits in pygame.

Comment: Pygame will either implement a game loop for you, in which case it should give you a delta-t for each frame (or a global desired FPS, from which you can easily figure out delta-t), or it requires you to implement it yourself.  I haven't used pygame before, but I'll take a look at it soon and see if I can get you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use threading's Timer Object:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: The problem with this solution is: "The interval the timer will wait before executing its action may not be exactly the same as the interval specified by the user."  Maybe this is good enough for Gjorgji, maybe not.

Comment: What i need is a global timer so that all functions can lookup the time easily(i need to know the time as a function parameter)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified anything about the needs of your code, so we have no way of telling what is "better" in your scenario.  E.g. what does your app do with time, and why would you imagine there is a better way than taking a delta?  Do you need different pieces of code to synchronize with each other, etc?

Since you didn't specify, I'll give an all-encompassing answer :)

No matter what solution you use, if your code *needs* to be in sync, then you should centralize the code that provides time.

In a real-time video game, this is often done inside the top-level game loop, and time deltas (from the previous invocation) are passed to lower level code, rather than time indices.  This way, you can pass the same delta to all code, and expect it all to behave correctly.

If it doesn't need to be in sync (you're not doing simulations based on elapsed time), then just grab the current time throughout your code, and take local deltas, as you currently are.  This is a fine-enough practice, because the clock code in most programming languages is high level enough that you won't have significant code duplication.  You might do this in a business application (e.g. not allowing someone to take some action after a date or time), or in a progress dialog for any other application.

If you don't need synchronization, and don't actually care what the current time is, but simply need some code to be kicked off at semi-regular intervals, then simply use a timer (see utdmr's answer).

Accuracy:

If you don't have strong needs for accurate timing, then you can simply use the equivalent of a timer, or thread sleep (see utdmr's answer).

If you have mission critical needs for your timing accuracy (such as launching a rocket), then your hardware, OS, other apps, programming language etc all need to support real-time computing.  This is probably way beyond what you're looking for.

If you have somewhat strong needs for accuracy (such as a game, where jitter or skips in your timing will make your simulation visibly jerk, but won't end the world), then you'll need a more complicated setup.  An example of such as setup is available here:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

That code may not be arranged exactly how you need, but it can massage to suit your application's layout.  The basic premise is making a producer/consumer model for time, and divvying it out in fixed increments.

Comment: @Gjorgji: I don't fully understand the question.  Please expand your question with your program's requirements, what you've done so far, some code examples, and what specific problems you are running into.  Without those, it's wild guess work to answer :)

Comment: @Gjorgji: Where are you "setting t1 then checking if t2 - t1 = 1"?  The code you pasted doesn't say anything about discreet times, only deltas (`t`).  Also, please edit your question to add the code.  This is encouraged on stackoverflow.com, and is pretty awesome, IMO :)

Comment: Edited the code in the question and added a more precise question i hope